# How to send mail asynchronously as the last step in a program?

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous, sendmail

I have a C# console app which has a SendMail function as the very last step. Can i send this mail asynchronously or will the process end before the mail gets sent? Since the SendMail function is the very last step, i am concerned that the application will exit without waiting for the asynchronous SendMail process to complete. There are several steps happening before this function i

```
public static void function1()
{
    //step1 
    //step2
    SendMail();
}

public static void SendMail()
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    try
    {
        MailTemplate template = new MailTemplate();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        //set SMTP host and credentials
        //set mailMessage body, from_email, to_email, message body
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        mailMessage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code eg `void async SendEmail ...`  and where in the Console Apps event life cycle it is being called. Without this info its pretty difficult to help you. Please read [ask] for other tips on writing better questions.

Comment: You realize that what you show isn't actually asynchronous, right? If you are doing something asynchronous, can you show that part? (The question as written now should technically be closed for not being reproducible).

Answer (score 0):

A few points here: first, in the code sample you show, you're decidedly *not* sending the email asynchronously. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `SmtpClient.Send` method clearly states that "This method blocks while the e-mail is transmitted."

if you *were* sending the email asynchronously, you would, in fact, have to do something to prevent the console application from closing before the mail is done sending.

With that said, if sending the email is the very last thing that the program does (i.e. it has no other work to do at the time) then doing this asynchronously won't really help you anyway. My usual analogy is ordering at a restaurant with 10 people: if the first guy's not ready when the waiter comes by, he'll take the other 9 people's orders first and then come back to him. That's basically how async/await works in C#. However, what you have here is analogous to a restaurant that only has one person in it; the waiter literally has nothing to do *other* than to wait for the guy to be ready to order, so asynchronous can't help here at all - the waiter's stuck waiting for the guy to be ready to order either way.